# Filter filtered results in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to filter a model by multiple parameters.

First, I find those objects with a first name that contains query param:

```
if (firstName){
    User.find({firstName: new RegExp(firstName, "i")}, function (err, users) {
        filteredUsers = users;
    });
}
```

Then, I want to continue filtering `filteredUsers` like:

```
if (lastName){
    filteredUsers.find({firstName: new RegExp(lastName, "i")}, function (err, users) {
        filteredUsers = users;
    })
}
```

and etc.

However, I am naturally getting this error:

```
 #<Object> is not a function
```

How can I accomplish filtering filtered results?

Comment: The way you have it doesn't make scene. You can't query a database with a plain array. you have to re plan your strategy I think.

Answer (score 2):

[aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is what you are looking for.
Your code will look like ( I haven't tried mongoose ):

```
Users.aggregate(
  [
    { $match: firstname ? { firstname: new RegExp(firstname, "i") } : {} },
    { $match: lastname ? { lastname: new RegExp(lastname, "i") } : {} }
  ]
);
```